# SVD: Calculate singular values of sub-matrix from SVD of full matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Say, I have calculated the singular value decomposition of a matrix
$$
A = USV^T
$$

Now, if I select an arbitrary number of rows of $A$, I get a sub-matrix of $A$, which I call $A_{[n]}$. I would like to calculate the **singular values of $A_{[n]}$** from the singular value decomposition above. Is that possible?

Many thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, answer is no. When you select $k$ rows of $A$ arbitrarily, you are effectively multiplying $A$ with a $k \times N$ matrix $P$ whose rows are from the $n \times n$ identity matrix. Thus, $A_{[n]}=PA = PUSV^T$